# Обработка данных из HTML формы

Tags: html, форма

У меня имеется форма

```
<form action="" name="myform" method="post">
    <textarea name="msg" cols="40" rows=”40” ></textarea>
    <input name="Submit" type=submit value="Отправить данные">
</form>
```

я принимаю данные хорошо, но данные принимаются из текстареа в виде одной строки, как сделать так, принять данные, что бы если он отделили свой текст через энтер например 3мя абзацами (не в смысле штмл абзацами, а просто энтер нажал и перешел на новую строку)

То есть как принять более мене форматированный текст с отступами и переходами на новую строку?

Comment: Перевод строк (ентер) - это спецсимволы \n и \r (и их сочетания).

Comment: а как их корректно обработать?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo str_replace("\n", "<br>", $_POST['msg']);
```

или

```
echo '<pre>'.$_POST['msg'].'</pre>';
```

Почитать подробно: [перевод строки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8#.D0.A2.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F).